# matplotlib says libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to install matplotlib version 2.0.0. I don't have root access, hence can't use sudo/apt-get When I tried installing matplotlib, it showed dependencies on freetype and libpng. So, I executed the following steps:

```
wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/libpng/libpng-1.6.34.tar.gz
tar -xzf libpng-1.6.34.tar.gz 
cd libpng-1.6.34/
./configure --prefix=/home/$username$/
make
make check
make install

cd ..
wget http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/freetype/freetype-2.5.3.tar.gz
tar xzf freetype-2.5.3.tar.gz
cd freetype-2.5.3
./configure --prefix=/home/$username$ --without-png
make && make install
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/$username$/lib/pkgconfig

pip install matplotlib==2.0.0
```

Which worked perfectly fine. But when I do `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` it throws the following error:

```
ImportError: libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What OS are you using?  On most Linux variants the directory containing the library would need to be added to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Solved it using the answer that was posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042437/matplotlib-says-libpng16-so-16-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or?noredirect=1#comment1698610_1042437)